# Memcached Error Code 48

Tags: php, memcached

sometimes my memcached server returns the following error:

```
Zend\Cache\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'SERVER FAILED TO ALLOCATE OBJECT'
```

Can anyone explain what this error mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The memcached memory was full, the error message was a little bit confusing...

Answer (score 0):

When there is no more space in memcached, you get this error.

To get Memcached total usage:

```
>> echo "stats" | nc 127.0.0.1 11211 | grep bytes
```

To flush the memory from your memcached server, you can do this from your CLI

```
>> echo 'flush_all' | netcat localhost 11211

>> sudo service memcached restart
```